# Can I remove nengine.dll from my machine?

Tags: windows-7, malware, malware-removal, avast

I recently started seeing an error message when starting up my pc:

```
nengine.dll is not a proper application extention.
```

Not recognising this nengine.dll, I did a quick search [online](http://www.freefixer.com/library/file/nengine.dll-106324/) and found it's some sort of malware.

So I deleted it. Now I'm getting the following:

[image]

Obviously, something is still trying to call it on start up.

I can't seem to find any method of removing this annoying dialog without downloading some 'nengine-remover' software. I'm wary of replacing one piece of malware with another.

Has anyone encountered this before and does anyone know how I could remove it once and for all?

My anti-virus software is the free version of AVAST, if that makes any difference.

**UPDATE**

Helpful advice [here](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc), if slightly dated.

In the process of trying to solve this problem - Oct 14th 2014

Comment: Detailed removal instructions are at [Nextlive “Nengine.dll” Removal Guide](http://www.malwareremovalguides.info/nextlive-nengine-dll-removal-guide/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Autoruns for Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to search for `nengine.dll` or `Newnext.me` in the Everything tab, and delete all the entries that you find. For good measures, search carefully also for
`nengine` or `Newnext`. Reboot to verify if you were successful in eradicating it.

Once the problem is fixed, scan your computer with anti-malware software, because very often this adware comes bundled with other adware or even spyware that you didn't notice yet.
[Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php) is recommended, but is not the only one - some other
good ones are suggested by the link in your post, and running more than one is safer.
Many of the mentioned products also have online scans (normally requiring either Java or
Internet Explorer).

Comment: Cheers Harry, I'll try this out after work

Answer (score 1):

A detailed explanation/solution to your problem is given [here](http://deletemalware.blogspot.com/2014/04/remove-newnextme-nenginedll-error-pop.html)

Once the Malware is removed. Restart your PC and scan it with [JRT](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/junkware-removal-tool/), [AdwCleaner](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/), and [Combofix (recommended)](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/).
Install MalwareBytes Anti-Malware along with Microsoft Security Essentials (I am using the MAM-MSE combo successfully for years)

Answer (score 1):

Great answer from Harry there for you but I just wanted to point something out:

Ideally you would have unregistered the Dll prior to deleting it from the system. For anyone that has this issue in the  future, once you locate the dll:

**Unregistering the .DLL file**

From the desktop, on the taskbar, select Start | Run | Type: cmd.exe | Press return.

**Important:** For Windows Vista and higher you must run the command prompt as 'an administrator'.  On Windows 8 (for example) go to the Start screen, simply type 'cmd' to search for the app, right-click the app returned and select 'Run as administrator' at the bottom of the screen.  Example:

You should either use 'CD' to change to the relevant directory (folder), or enter the full path to the file.

```
regsvr32 -u `<filename>.dll`
```

or

```
regsvr32 -u `<path>\<filename>.dll`
```

where `<path>` is the path to the file, and `<filename>` is the name of the file.

You will probably also have a left over Startup Entry from Malware that has been removed by your Security Programs.

Scan your System again if problem remains after scanning, take those Entries out of Startup using msconfig.

Or you should can use this windows Program to do that, too:

"Autoruns for Windows v11.32"

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not a recommended option, since it may break other things. 
Try using a registry cleaner to remove references to non-existent objects.